# handling the duplicated elements & pushing them into the array in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple checkbox function and what it does is once the checkboxes are checked it saves the selected elements into the `array A`. and push the `array A` into the `array B` that is outside of the function, which means that every time, I use the checkbox, the duplicated data will be saved in `Array B` but I am trying to make it like if the `array B` already has the same `elements id` that is pushed from `array A` then don't add it. Is there any simple way to fix that issue?

JS

```
var last_check_elements = [];

function whatever(){
       $('.check').on('click', function() {

                  var checkArray = [];
                  $('.check').each(function() {
                    checkArray = {id: $(this).attr('id'), value: $(this).prop('checked')};

                   last_check_elements.push(checkArray);
                  });
}
```

Comment: You are reassigning `checkArray` on every iteration, and it is never an array, it's just an object, except in the case that there are no iterations to make, in which case it's an *empty* array, which isn't very useful...

Comment: is `last_check_elements` caching every checkbox that has been checked? Is there any reason to remove data from `last_check_elements`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have other functions that are dealing with the `last_check_elements` is there anyway to do..?

Comment: @Damon, I have other functions that are dealing with the `last_check_elements`  that should be placed outside of the whatever function..

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do there, exactly. You should probably first clarify (or fix) your current code

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to store some kind of data about each checkbox every time a checkbox is clicked, it would be better to use an object. Otherwise, you will have to iterate through your storage array every time you want to update it (to check if the element already exists).

If you run the below snippet, you will see that the object is updated with every click.

```js
const checkboxState = {}

function updateCheckboxState ({target: checkbox}) {
  checkboxState[checkbox.id] = {
    id: checkbox.id,
    value: checkbox.checked
  }
  // remove log, just here to show behavior
  console.log(checkboxState)
}

$('.check').on('click', updateCheckboxState)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="1">1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="2">2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="3">3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="4">4</label>
```

If you need an array of these values at some point, you can do the following:

```
Object.values(checkboxState)
```